# Delete an Item from a RecyclerView and add it to a second RecyclerView in the same activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

This is my questio.

I have 2 RecyclerViews in the same Activity. The first one(RecView1) has an adapter (of course) and the second one (RecView2) has different one.

I would like to:

- on click on a button of the card in RecView1, the card will be deleted from the list and it will appear into RecView2.

I did it making a really bad thing I think :

in the RecView1 adapter:

```
    public LSAdapterBottom(List<ListaInfo> sList,List<ListaInfo> lSMain, LSActivity lSActivity) {

    this.sList = sList;//list of the current adapter
    this.lSMain = lSMain; //second list where I want to put the item here deleted
    this.lSActivity = lSActivity; //activity which has the two recview 
    }        


    public void onBindViewHolder(LSViewBottomHolder cViewHolder, final int i) {
        final Item item = sList.get(i);

        cViewHolder.ics.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                lSMain.add(item);
                lSActivity.notifyRitornoInLista(); //public method of the activity which simply calls the other adapter to invoke the notifyDataSetChanged() to update the other recview.

                sList.remove(i);
                notifyDataSetChanged();


            }
        });
```

I think it is really dirty solution, but it is working. I'd like to know a cleaner way to do reach the same result.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: just a thought, using interface rather than public method. when click event occurs on RV1 to remove item through listener it'll be notified on Activity & then that item will be added on RV2. then refresh the view.

Comment: ok. but you think it's a good think to pass the listActivity to the adapter?

Comment: I'd like to pass Item (which will be deleted from RV1) from the adapter (of RV1) through the interface to receive in the Activity (from where RV1, RV2 initialize), then add that Item on RV2.